# cron task problem

Tags: cron, automation, scheduled-task

I have a cron task as

```
6,36 * * * * python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log/newlog
```

it is supposed to run at every 6th and 36th minute of each hour.

But for some how the system runs this task 4 processes/times each time. This task is to update database, and it causes problem when three processes updating database at the same time.

I have 4 tasks listing in /var/spool/cron/root, this is one of the tasks

What possibly went wrong here?

Thanks

**Edit**:

```
Oct 9 20:06:01 online CROND[7882]: (root) CMD (python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log/newslog)  
Oct 9 20:06:01 online CROND[7883]: (root) CMD (python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log/newslog)  
Oct 9 20:06:01 online CROND[7888]: (root) CMD (python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log//newslog)  
Oct 9 20:06:01 online CROND[7890]: (root) CMD (python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log//newslog)
```

Comment: What does your log say?

Comment: I mean /var/log/cron.log rather than the one in the crontab line above.

Comment: Oct  9 20:06:01 online CROND[7882]: (root) CMD (python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log/newslog)
Oct  9 20:06:01 online CROND[7883]: (root) CMD (python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log/newslog)
Oct  9 20:06:01 online CROND[7888]: (root) CMD (python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log//newslog)
Oct  9 20:06:01 online CROND[7890]: (root) CMD (python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log//newslog)

Comment: 4 lines of 

"Oct  9 20:06:01 online CROND[7890]: (root) CMD (python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log//newslog)"

running at the same time, now sure what is going on

Comment: FYI: I have 4 tasks listing in /var/spool/cron/root

Comment: You should post follow-ups with listings like that as an edit of your answer. Then you can use quote block formatting to make it more readable. I'll take care of it for you.

Comment: "now sure what is going on" - **now** sure or **not** sure?

Comment: Please take a few minutes to correct your many typos - your mistakes are making assisting you difficult. For example, according to the lines from syslog that you pasted, you have two similar but different commands running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the result of the following command? If there is more than one number listed then cron is running more than once which could cause this problem.

```
pgrep -l cron
```

Comment: 3674 crond
6335 crond
20785 crond
22084 crond

Comment: i have this output when i run pgrep -l cron
"
3674 crond

6335 crond

20785 crond

22084 crond
"

It looks i have 4 copies of crond  are running at the same time?

Comment: Thanks! i think problem should be gone (after i rebooted my server). For somehow I have 4 instances of crond running at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

By 'I have 4 tasks listing in /var/spool/cron/root', do you mean:

'I have 4 lines in root's crontab, all the same thing.'?

Please paste the output of 'crontab -l'. If it looks anything like:

```
6,36 * * * * python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log/newlog
6,36 * * * * python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log/newlog
6,36 * * * * python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log/newlog
6,36 * * * * python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log/newlog
```

That's definitely the problem :0

Comment: sorry, no i have for different tasks. the one 
6,36 * * * * python /usr/local/news.py >> /var/log/newlog

is only one of them

Comment: In that case, you don't happen to have started 4 instances of crond somehow, have you? Is this the only task that runs 4 copies at the same time, or do all tasks do so? Also, please paste the output of 'crontab -l' into your question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like two of the runs have a slightly different syntax. Could you check /etc/crontab and /etc/cron.d to check you don't have copies of the command there?